# Xorg configuration for additional monitor

Tags: xorg, displaylink

I've been struggling to get a third screen working which stopped after changing the monitor (previously this did work on USB displayLink). I had EDID errors on startup so now have generated my own xorg.conf file as below. The screen now starts, but shows a ubuntu loading screen stating 'Started Light Display Manager' but isn't recognised in the screen settings.

```
Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "DisplayLinkDevice"
driver         "displaylink"
Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
Option "UseEDID" "False"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "Monitor0"
ModelName "S24D590"
VendorName "SAM"
# Monitor Manufactured week 23 of 2015
# EDID version 1.3
# Analog Display
Option "SyncOnGreen" "true"
DisplaySize 520 290
Gamma 2.20
Option "DPMS" "true"
Horizsync 30-81
VertRefresh 56-75
# Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
#Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
Modeline    "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "Monitor1"
ModelName "S24D590"
VendorName "SAM"
# Monitor Manufactured week 23 of 2015
# EDID version 1.3
# Analog Display
Option "SyncOnGreen" "true"
DisplaySize 520 290
Gamma 2.20
Option "DPMS" "true"
Horizsync 30-81
VertRefresh 56-75
# Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
#Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
Modeline    "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "DisplayLinkMonitor"
ModelName "S24D590"
VendorName "SAM"
# Monitor Manufactured week 23 of 2015
# EDID version 1.3
# Analog Display
Option "SyncOnGreen" "true"
DisplaySize 520 290
Gamma 2.20
Option "DPMS" "true"
Horizsync 30-81
VertRefresh 56-75
# Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
#Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
#Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
Modeline    "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
EndSection

#Section "Monitor"
#   Identifier      "DisplayLinkMonitor"
#EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen1"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth    24
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    Modes "1920x1080"
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "DisplayLinkScreen"
Device         "DisplayLinkDevice"
Monitor        "DisplayLinkMonitor"
DefaultDepth    24
SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080"
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ubuntu ignores xorg.conf. You could put this stuff in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, but you're probably better off using xrandr or arandr or unity-control-center to configure your monitors.